# Throw custom exception in `method_missing` without calling .new

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I'm redefining `method_missing` for a proxy-style object. I would like to be able to throw a custom `NoMethodError` (or some other error if `NoMethodError` is a particular problem, I used an `ArgumentError` below) to give the caller more information as to why the particular proxy object doesn't have the method.

However, when I try to throw any exception from `method_missing` I get into a recursive loop that eventually results in `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

**I would like to be able to do something like this:**

```
class X
  define method_missing(symbol, *args)
    raise ArgumentError("Here: #{symbol} ")
  end
end

x = X.new
x.a # Raise an ArgumentError, not a SystemStackError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can raise an exception by calling the exception class as a method like that. It can't find a method named `ArgumentError` so it tries calling your `method_missing` to see if you can handle it, then you try calling it again, and the cycle repeats (try it in a fresh `irb` session without your code loaded, you'll see it raises a `NoMethodError`).

I believe the most popular way to throw an exception would be 2 parameters to `raise`:

```
raise ArgumentError, "Here: #{symbol}"
```

although if you want to be a bit more explicit you can also pass in an instance of the exception class:

```
raise ArgumentError.new("Here: #{symbol}")
```

Comment: Haha oops. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did the same thing after dong Python at work... thanks